# Getting 504 - Gateway Time-Out error when trying to render a PDF file with DomPDF

Tags: nginx, timeout, dompdf

When I try to render the PDF file with DomPDF, I keep getting a 504 error.
It takes 60 seconds of loading to give me the error.
And it takes so long cause of the huge data coming from the database that I want to write in the PDF file.

I already tried the steps [on this site](http://www.nginxtips.com/504-gateway-time-out-using-nginx/) but it keeps giving me the error after 60 seconds.

Comment: Some conf files may help us find the problem. I encourage you to edit your question.

Comment: 504 is a gateway timeout. I'm guessing your PHP script timeout is 60 seconds, after which nginx stops waiting. If you can get more details on the error, that would be helpful. But as a first attempt to fix try increasing the value of `max_execution_time`.